# Problems With ASP:Login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I built a website with Visual Studio 2012.  I used asp:login in my site and when I click on the Login button, the page refreshes but shows the last page and no login.  I tried asp:login with empty txt user and txt pass fields.  But the Validator doesn't work either.  Plugins used:Telerik.  This is a web site, not a web application.

Update:SQL Server and AUTH. is Correct
Update 2:My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network defaultCredentials="false"
           host="mail.aryapro.ir" port="110"
           userName="noreply@aryapro.ir"
           password="Arya12345"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="404.html"></customErrors>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-us" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="1440"/>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule"/>
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
    </httpModules>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Telerik.Skin" value="Metro"/>
    <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RadUploadModule"/>
      <remove name="RadCompression"/>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
      <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=144.76.74.98;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=**********;User ID=********;Password=*******;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Update 3:My asp:login is in a master page
Update 4:My Database is configured and it is correct.

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using? Forms? And how are the credentials stored? Web.config? SQL Server?

Comment: Have you configured the membership database? There are resources here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fx93s7w.aspx, specifically this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx

Comment: Could you post the code of the login control and anything associated with it (e.g. validators)? Also check there are no script errors on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is from this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

When I changed this to Default nameset,My site is working now!

Answer (score -2):

It might not be working because your asp:login is in a master page. The (default), way that forms authentication works is that it will try to redirect to the login page (login.aspx).  However, you can configure it to look for a page with a different name.

This MSDN article (step 3) briefly explains it: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb
Here is another MSDN article that thoroughly discusses all of the concepts: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb

Comment: You can still have a Login control on the master page, all you need to do is also specify the LoginUrl property and make that page, if it doesn't exist the user will just get a 404. Also once the user is logged in, it will try to redirect from the login page (FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) to the ReturnUrl specified in the DefaultUrl property of the FormsAuthentication config settings, or default.aspx if one is not specified (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl.aspx)

Comment: #Sean their is nothing in Sepehr Mohammadi's code to indicate that he is doing this. Perhaps you might want to post a better answer below instead of downvoting and commenting on my answer.  My answer is consistent with the recommended way from Microsoft.

Comment: I have asked for code for the login so I can help, there simply isn't enough information to accurately answer right now. The problem he has described sounds like there is something wrong with the authentication of the user, not hitting a 404 from a missing login page. I am perfectly entitled to downvote any answer I feel is not helpful and potentially misleading according to the rules of the site, which also state that I should explain why I have downvoted. I have done that and even provided links to the documentation. If you're bothered about 2 rep I can undo it but that won't help anyone.